# Cloudformation Reuse EBS Volume

Tags: amazon-cloudformation

I am using cloudformation to manage my infra, and I am facing an issue,
if i want to change instance type of an instance, a new instance will be launched with new EBS volume, is there any way to reattach existing ebs Volume

Comment: Changing the instance type should only reboot the instance, not replace it. That is specified in the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-instancetype

Comment: sorry, But these instance is autoscaling with one instance in one ASG for health check, what should we do in that case

Comment: Create an AMI from the EBS volume.